# Correct syntax for echo

Tags: cron, echo

In a crontab I have the following:

```
* * * * * echo "Hello" >> /Users/gamsk/Desktop/test.txt >> Users/gamsk/Desktop/testlog.log
```

However, this is creating the file test.txt but it is empty.
I have tried double, simple quoation marks and double and single ">". Could you help me discern where the problem is?

Thank you

Comment: The problem is using >> twice. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I read elsewhere that syntax can be used to get a log since I have no log of my crontab jobs.